# Confused about public, static and private methods/classes/variables in C#

Tags: c#, oop, static, private, public

I'm a beginner in programming with C# and coming from a Python background.

I'm confused about the keywords public and static. Can someone please clarify the difference for me?

(Btw, I already know that Private variables/methods can never be accessed outside the function, whereas Public can be)

Here is just something I randomly tried to understand the difference between static, and non-static methods.

```
using System;

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        int[] anArray =  getAnArray();

        foreach (int x in anArray) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine (x);
        }

        MainClass m = new MainClass ();
        foreach (int x in anArray) 
        {
            m.Print(x);
        }
    }

    public static int[] getAnArray() 
    {
        int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        return myArray;
    }

    public void Print(int x) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

I understand that to use the non-static method Print, I first need to create an instance of the MainClass, then access the method by doing m.Print()

However I don't understand when exactly to use which. As far as I can see it would be a lot easier if Print was static, as I wouldn't need to create a new instance of my own function.

For eg, this would be simpler

```
private static void Print(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine (x);
}
```

And call the Print function with Print(x) instead of creating the instance of Main first.

So basically when to use what? When to use static or non-static in regard to not only methods but variables and even classes? (For eg when should I use public static class MainClass)

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Generally, `static` vs `non-static` can really be independent to each developer, there is no ground rules. Generally, people tend to use `static` methods when it doesn't make sense to create an instance of a class in order to consume the method. This is generally used in many "utility" classes. Some people generally don't like to use `static` at all, as it is less testable.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212437/what-is-the-difference-between-public-static-public-and-static-method

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212437/what-is-the-difference-between-public-static-public-and-static-method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`static` members are class members, and shared between all instances of that class.

`public` methods/properties are available to other classes. It's possible to have a `public static` member which is available to other classes.

You can't access a non-static member from a static member.

If a function doesn't need access to any instance variables then it can be made `static` for a slight performance gain, but there are more useful ways to use static members.

Some uses for static off the top of my head:

- Singletons (you create a protected constructor that is accessed by a static variable inside the class)
- Console.WriteLine is static
- Locks/semaphores (where there is only one available at the class level that is shared by all instances)

If something makes sense to be shared by all instances of a class, make it static

Comment: *If a function doesn't need access to any instance variables then it can be made public for a slight performance gain* I think you meant "can be made `static`". Also, I wouldn't confuse beginner programmers with the term "performance gain", where this is really a micro-optimization which is usually neglectable. You don't want people going around spreading static methods all over the place.

Comment: Hm, okay I think I understand the difference, but when should I, in general, use which? And why don't many people like to use static at all?

Comment: Yeah thanks for your answer! I'll read some other programs and read more into Objects and classes to understand better.

Answer (score 2):

Small, self-explaining example of public/non-static and static methods in use:

```
Car car1 = new Car();
car1.setBrand("Ford"); //public non-static method
Car car2 = new Car();
car2.setBrand("Opel"); //public non-static method

Car.CompareParameters(car1, car2); //static method
```

Basically, non-static methods and properties describe objects of such class.

You can't call `Car.setBrand()` - non-static method using class name.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb:

**Static methods**
The `static` keyword makes the method directly accessible without having to create an instance of an object. As such, any state or side-effects it has will be `static`, ie "global". So only use `static` to create pure functions, ie methods that derive a return value from their inputs only, neither reading or writing state from outside the method.

The use of `static` is a trade-off between simplifying code and testing. The more side-effects you put in to a `static` method, the harder your code will be to test.

**public methods**
Anything marked `public` is accessible throughout your application. Marking something `internal` restricts it to just that assembly (you can view the term "assembly" as equivalent to a project in your solution") and `private` restricts it to only being assessable within a class/struct.

If you follow the principle of encapsulation, then the rule to follow is use `private` all the time, only using `internal` if you need to. And only use `public` if you really have to.